# Simulate multiple datasets in R, and change seed for each simulation

Tags: r, vectorization, simulation

I want to generate 1 million simulated datasets and save them in a list column.

The problem I run into is that every generated dataset is identical, which I assume is a result of the operation being vectorized. Is there a way to maintain the speed of a vectorized operation while changing the seed for each execution of rbinom()?

```
library(tidyverse)

SIMS <- 100
df <- 
    tibble(
        sim = 1:5,
        data = 
            list(
                tibble(
                    read = 1:100,
                    events = rbinom(n=SIMS, size=1e3, prob = .25),
                    trials = 1e3
                )
        )
    )

df
```

[image]

```
head(df$data[[1]])
```

[image]

```
head(df$data[[2]])
```

[image]

I have tried using parallel::mclapply(), which solves the seed issue, but the performance is nowhere near as fast as the vectorized operation.

```
BASERATE <- .25 
DAILY_N <- 1e3
DURATION <- 500

time_to_insight <- function(){
  tibble(
    read = 1:DURATION,
    events = rbinom(n=DURATION, size=DAILY_N, prob = BASERATE),
    trials = DAILY_N
  ) 
}

temp <- 
  parallel::mclapply(
    X = 1:1000,
    FUN = time_to_insight,
    mc.cores = 8L
  )
```

Comment: "every generated dataset is identical".  I don't think so.  Your `data` is a list of length 1, so it is recycled as per tidyverse's standard procedures.  I suspect the diffenece in speed is due to the fact that your paralellisation is generating a million different tibbles, where as your stadard version merely copies the same tibble a million times.

Comment: My previous comment should have started "The problem I run into is that every generated dataset is identical, which I assume is a result of the operation being vectorized".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (almost) maintain the speed of your original function by generating the realisations of your random variable (`events`) for all of your simulations at the same time.  This is possible because your event probability remains constant for all the simulations.

Here's how I would do it.  First write a function to generate all your simulations at the same time.

```
generateTibble <- function() {
  tibble() %>% 
    expand(sim=1:5, read=1:100, trials=1000) %>% 
    mutate(events=rbinom(n=nrow(.), size=1000, prob=0.25))
}
```

And use it

```
df <- generateTibble()
df
# A tibble: 500 × 4
     sim  read trials events
   <int> <int>  <dbl>  <int>
 1     1     1   1000    246
 2     1     2   1000    232
 3     1     3   1000    258
 4     1     4   1000    233
 5     1     5   1000    259
 6     1     6   1000    251
 7     1     7   1000    254
 8     1     8   1000    263
 9     1     9   1000    267
10     1    10   1000    266
# … with 490 more rows
```

Demonstrate that realisations do not repeat across `sim`s:

```
df %>% group_by(sim) %>% group_map(head, n=2)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 3
   read trials events
  <int>  <dbl>  <int>
1     1   1000    246
2     2   1000    232

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 3
   read trials events
  <int>  <dbl>  <int>
1     1   1000    255
2     2   1000    261

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 × 3
   read trials events
  <int>  <dbl>  <int>
1     1   1000    234
2     2   1000    239

[[4]]
# A tibble: 2 × 3
   read trials events
  <int>  <dbl>  <int>
1     1   1000    252
2     2   1000    258

[[5]]
# A tibble: 2 × 3
   read trials events
  <int>  <dbl>  <int>
1     1   1000    255
2     2   1000    258
```

Compare the speed of the new function with the original (faulty) version:

```
SIMS <- 100

originalFunction <- function() {
df <- 
  tibble(
    sim = 1:5,
    data = 
      list(
        tibble(
          read = 1:100,
          events = rbinom(n=SIMS, size=1e3, prob = .25),
          trials = 1e3
        )
      )
  )
df
}

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(originalFunction, generateTibble, times=100)
Unit: nanoseconds
             expr min lq  mean median uq  max neval
 originalFunction  42 43 52.95     44 44  877   100
   generateTibble  47 48 68.14     48 54 1403   100
```

So, a 28% increase in mean execution time.  Is that reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your simulation works, it might be possible to create all the data for all the simulations first, and then group them into a list to get the original format with unique data.

```
n = 5
SIMS = 100
set.seed(42)
df <- 
  tibble(
    sim = rep(1:n, each = SIMS),
    read = rep(1:SIMS, times = n),
    events = rbinom(n=SIMS*n, size=1e3, prob = .25), 
    trials = 1e3) %>%
  nest(data = -sim)
```

Result

```
> head(df$data[[1]])
# A tibble: 6 × 3
   read events trials
  <int>  <int>  <dbl>
1     1    240   1000
2     2    262   1000
3     3    240   1000
4     4    250   1000
5     5    214   1000
6     6    244   1000
> head(df$data[[2]])
# A tibble: 6 × 3
   read events trials
  <int>  <int>  <dbl>
1     1    247   1000
2     2    260   1000
3     3    253   1000
4     4    245   1000
5     5    259   1000
6     6    247   1000
```